# Front end damage

Tags: vw, passat, frontend

1. Front damage to bumper[image: radiatorhanging][image: cracked radiatorand busted hose]

To avoid an accident I swerved into a ditch and my front end slammed down.  My radiator is hanging and I know somthing cracked cause I smelled it.  I was 5min from home, was able to drive home and no air bags deployed. Hope likely is out that my car is repairable or does this mean total loss?  It is a 2017 VW Passat

[image: damage]

Comment: All damage is repairable.  It is a matter of cost.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome.  Are you able to do work on the car yourself?  If yes, then post some photos of the damage.  If no, then you will be best just getting some quotes from local mechanics to decide what is best to do.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that "total loss" is very much an insurance term.  Insurance companies have a criteria, usually proprietary, where if the damage as they assess it exceeds a certain percentage of the car's value, they term it "totaled" and offer you a settlement based on the market value of the car.  Most people are under the mistaken belief that when they say "totaled" then you are bound to accept their deal and hand over the title to the car.  (Also note that if you have a loan on the car, the lender may have a say in this as well, so in that case it's not necessarily up to you.)

Sometimes they total a car over some relatively insignificant damage and you may believe that you can repair it yourself or have it repaired and be on your way again.  In that case you can request a settlement that is probably less than the car's market value, since they are not getting the car, and take the money and do what you will with it.

Some people take the first option and then "buy the car back" from the insurance company.  That's also an option but it's a separate deal from the settlement.  But when you do this, in almost all cases you get a "SALVAGE" title.  This indicates to any future buyer that the car was totaled.  If you take the second option you keep your original title and it will not say SALVAGE.

Now to your specific question: Only someone who knows auto repair can determine if it's repairable or not but generally unless the car looks as if it came out of a crushing machine, it's repairable. Either assess the damage yourself and get some quotes for parts and any repairs you cannot do yourself or take it to a shop you trust and get their estimate.  Insurance companies usually have "adjusters" who will take a look, usually a quick look, and make an estimate.  They may or may not be all that accurate.

I'll give you an example:  My high-school aged daughter rear ended a school bus with her Ford Escape.  The damage was pretty extensive but after looking it over I determined that all the damaged parts were bolt-on and I could fix it for not a lot more than my $1000 insurance deductible.  So I ordered the parts and repaired the car for about $1100.  The only thing I was unable to do myself was to paint the hood which came primed but not painted.  So I took it to a local shop and had it painted to match.

All we well until she rear-ended someone else, but that's another story...

Comment: A few years ago, my Mom's car was in a hail storm, so got a lot of dents in the top of it. She calls me up and says she'll now have to get a new car. I asked her if it still runs fine? She said yes. I also asked her if she cared about the dents? She said no. I told her to take the money from the insurance company and call it a day. No need for a new car. No need to get it fixed. I told her the car owed her nothing. She's still driving the same car today.

Comment: I've noticed that a lot of times hail damage will resolve itself over time.

Comment: Hadn't thought about it, but metal does have memory. It wants to go back to where it started. I can see that happening.

Comment: My Mom's car had some hail damage once and as it was sitting in the sun, every few minutes there was a fairly loud "pop".  I wondered what it was and I went to the car and watched it for a while and it was the dents literally popping out.  Only the really deep ones remained visible over time.